# Any solution to Upload bin/hex to openCM904 board without using/install IDE

Tags: windows, hex, stm32, binaryfiles

i want to upload my compiled bin/hex to the 'OpenCM9.04' board via some direct flash tool OR command line but without using any IDE install/Use. i need to send only the bin/hex to flash to board without going through the code over IDE.
is there any way to do so. Please suggest!

Comment: I tried to flash it using serial uart on board which allow me to upload bootloader but unable to upload compiled arduino ide sketch. Please suggest aome solution to resolve this. Thanks.